# why after Hibernate4 save() the database will change?

Tags: hibernate-4.x

why after execute such code without `flush()`,database will change?

```
public static void main(String args[]){

ApplicationContext ac = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("src/main/resources/config/spring/spring-common.xml");

SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory)ac.getBean("sessionFactory");

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

Student student = new Student();

student.setName("zyc");

session.save(student);
}
```

I use this class to create sessionFactory.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "database will change" here if Student is defined to use IDENTITY for id generation.  Meaning that the insert for Student will happen immediately on the call to save *for IDENTITY* based generators.

Comment: wow,I never think about it was caused by id generation,thanks for a lot :)